# Log in to Stack Overflow app

Tags: support, stackapps, iphone

I just got the Stack Overflow app on iPhone, but I can't find where or how to log into my account.  This is the screen that I see:

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks!

P.S.: Clicking on "Offline" shows me nothing.

Comment: Stack Overflow has no official iPhone app. Which app is this?

Comment: Oh   The design similarities fooled me.   Its called mystacks and is on app store.  Is stackoverflow planning on releasing an app anytime?  Thank you

Comment: @NickB Not any time soon, far as I know. Or at least it's not high on the priority list. We do have a relatively decent mobile web interface, though.

Comment: MyStacks [is listed on StackApps](http://stackapps.com/questions/2965/mystacks-stack-overflow-trilogy-iphone-app-free) - you might be able to get some support there.

Comment: @nic - simply viewing the website in the mobile version is pretty good. You might want to try it as well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not our application; it's from a third party developer hitting the API.  To get any fixes you'll have to contact them.

We do not have an official native mobile application in production at this time.